# Rails app unable to store longitude data larger than 15 precisions in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Im using geocoder gem in my rails app, the lat and long are double precision in my postgres db.
Some of my longitude data are greater than 15 precision (174.83837440000002), and the float type generates double precision can only store 15 precision data, when stored in my database, it just truncated, anyone have this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making mistake using double precision field for this.

First of all double precision is inexact field type. Therefore, as we know from CS 101, data stored there are subjected to rounding error. Not very good, when we thinking about coordinates.

Double precision in postgres has range "15 decimal digits precision". Therefore, behaviour you're describing is perfectly normal.

Field type, you should've been using is decimal - it has user defined precision: "up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point". It will be mapped into Ruby bigdecimal, so it will be exact representation of data (without rounding error). More information about postrges data types can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) and about using decimal within Rails migration [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column).

However, when you're using Postgres you probably want to use PostGis extension. It has special field type for storing location data "native support for spatial features represented on "geographic" coordinates (sometimes called 'geodetic' coordinates, or 'lat/lon', or 'lon/lat')". More info can be found [here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry) (and geocoder supports it, however in [limited range](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/261)).